# IE and white-space

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer

I have PHP creating an inline unordered list from an array. For each of these list items, I need to specify "white-space: nowrap" because I have checkboxes next to text, and they should not be separated. However, the list should otherwise be wrapping normally, because it shouldn't apply outside the list items.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($nonfiction as $nonficid => $nonficgenre) {
        echo "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"genre[]\" value=\"$nonficgenre\"";
        if (in_array($nonficgenre, $selectedgenres)) {
            echo " checked=\"checked\"";
        }
        echo " /><span class=\"genrelabel\">$nonficgenre</span></li> ";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

And in my CSS (note: the whole list is in a div of class "listdivs"):

```
.listdivs li {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, which wraps the list around at the appropriate break. But IE ignores the legitimate white spaces and prints the whole list out on one line. How can I compensate for this?

Answer (score 0):

try to add an span arround content.

```
.listdivs li {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.listdivs li span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($nonfiction as $nonficid => $nonficgenre) {
        echo "<li><span><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"genre[]\" value=\"$nonficgenre\"";
        if (in_array($nonficgenre, $selectedgenres)) {
            echo " checked=\"checked\"";
        }
        echo " /><span class=\"genrelabel\">$nonficgenre</span></span></li> ";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This trick  is used alot in some ui, like jqueryui, yahooui, extjs

Comment: I just tried this as is first and it didn't do anything, so I tried just using the nowrap in the span and not the list item. That worked insofar as it broke the line, but it ignored the nowrap. I may just have to alter my structure for IE.